# PictureBox Invalidate took too much time

Tags: c#, picturebox

I don't know, why invalidate takes so much time. I write basic program and I don't know how to fix, to work smoothly.

```
while (_continue)
{
  try
  {
    string message = port.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("message");
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
  }
  catch (TimeoutException) {
  }
}
```

And paint function is:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("hi");
}
```

I change code without console write and work same or maybe worst.

Result is like: 100x "message" 1x "hi", 1x "message" 1x "hi" like 100x "message". I need use paint more often.

Comment: You should explain a little more what you are actually trying to achieve. It feels like you have a fundamental design flaw here. What puzzles me is that you get a "hi" at all. `Paint` can afaik only be called when you stop blocking the UI thread with the upper loop. `Invalidate` does not lead to `Paint` immediatly, it just posts a message that `Paint` should be called when your code is done.

Comment: I got some values from serial port. I draw this values. Here is just example for my structure. If I have delay is not big problem, but I have too big. How can I call Paint immediatly? @RenéVogt

Comment: "Calling Paint" is not the best idea. I don't know where your upper loop is executed. You should think about making this an asynchronous task, best using `async/await`. Then you would not block the UI thread and the pictureBox1 had time to repaint. If you explain where that loop runs I may show an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `Paint` method gets called so rarely because your loop is blocking the UI thread. You should think about making this code asynchronous. Here is an example how this can be done:

```
public async Task ReadMessages()
{
    while (_continue)
    {
        try
        {
            string message = await Task.Run(() => port.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("message");
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
        catch (TimeoutException) {    }
    }
}
```

So this method returns to the caller while waiting for data from the `port`. When the `Task` executing `port.ReadLine()` finishes, this method continues execution at `Console.WriteLine` and invalidates the `pictureBox1`.

Then it loops, starts another task to read from the port and returns control to the caller again while waiting for data.

This way you don't block the UI thread and the `pictureBox1` has time to paint itself.

Comment: Yeah. Now is much better. Thank you.